# Correct thread lock / Loctite for computer screws

Tags: screws

On my laptop (mid 2012 MBP) I updated the ram, to do this i had to undo about 10 small screws on the base of the laptop.

When i did this the thread lock on these screws was stripped, and now some of them shake lose.

I want to take the screws out and apply thread lock to them to stop them becoming lose, but am a bit unsure as to which thread lock to use, and if it even matters, my only concern is using something to heavy duty and seizing the tiny screws or not something with good enough heat resistance. Ive looked on amazon for 'computer thread lock' but couldnt find much apart from generic thread lock. Is there a special product required or can i just use the normal on e ?

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember about Loctite is "a little dab will do you."  I use a toothpick to place the tiniest amount I can on the threads.  You only need enough to keep the screws from vibrating out.

As for removal, if you apply a bit of direct heat with a soldering iron, the screw will back right out with little to no effort.